# Composer autoload class not found

Tags: php, composer-php

I created a vendor library with this configuration:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Company\\PhpUtils\\": "src/" }
},
```

Directory structure:

```
php-utils/
---src/
------JSON/
--------Json.php
```

Json Class:

```
<?php

namespace Company\PhpUtils\JSON;
```

Now I include it as a dependency:

```
"company/php-utils": "1.0.0"
```

and use it in a symfony test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Controller;

use Company\PhpUtils\JSON\Json;
```

Run tests:

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit ./tests
PHPUnit 4.8.22 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Company\PhpUtils\JSON\Json' not found in...
```

The class Json is static... well... follows singleton pattern.

So...Easy question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: stupid question: have you run composer install or update after the changes made in composer.json?

Comment: Stupid answer. I did it, and tried composer dump-autoload as well. I modify the composer psr4.php and if I add the entry manually it works. If I hadn't done that, I wouldn't been opened this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In your phpunit command there's no bootstrap, change from:

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit ./tests
```

To:

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit ./tests --bootstrap ./vendor/autoload.php
```

Comment: We are talking about symfony standart proyect. In tje base folder there is a phpunit.xml.dist that includes app/autoload.php. And I said: if I add the entry namespace in vendor/composer/psr4.php file,everything works